# Replacing White Space in JSX for CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I want to remove white space from an object field so I can display it as a background image in CSS using JSX.

```
renderImage(singleMedia, type) {
  let mediaType = singleMedia.mediaType;
  if(type == "image")){
    var mediaPreview = singleMedia.mediaPreview.replace(/\s+/g, '%20');
    console.log("The original image was", singleMedia.mediaPreview, "The NEW ONE IS", mediaPreview);
    var divStyle = {
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + mediaPreview + ')'
    }
  }

 return(
        <div className="image-logo" style={divStyle}> </div>
    );
 }
```

I can render the image fine if mediaPreview has NO spaces. But when it does have a space, I still can't view it even after I add the %20.

When I run my code I get the following results: (But the output is still blank. The image only shows if I send one with no white space)

```
the original image was http://api.testing.ca/media/ad/no-smoking-sign (1).png The NEW ONE IS http://api.testing.ca/media/ad/no-smoking-sign%20(1).png
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to strip the white space and convert it to %20 within the divStyle?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not the whitespace, the problem is the end-parenthesis in the file name.  Instead of replacing white space with `%20` instead replace `)` with `%29`:

```
var mediaPreview = singleMedia.mediaPreview.replace(/\)/g, '%29');
```

The `url` token in CSS [ends when the first non-escaped `)` is found](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#url-token-diagram).

Alternatively, you can quote the entire URL:

```
var divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: 'url("' + mediaPreview + '")'
}
```

but then you would need to escape quotes instead.

Comment: Oh ok I see! I was able to do the alternative solution and it worked. Wondering why replacement isn't working. I copy pasted the first solution and got this: no-smoking-sign (1%29.png